# array_pop() expects array, boolean given for $event_type_term ->slug

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, terms, array

I have the following function I wrote …

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'events_permalink_structure', 10, 4);

function events_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%event_type%' ) ) {
        $event_type_term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'event_type' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%event_type%', array_pop( $event_type_term )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

When creating a new post I get the following Warnings in the backend …

> Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in
>   /Users/my/htdocs/wr/wp-content/themes/wr/functions.php on line 168
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /Users/my/htdocs/wr/wp-content/themes/wr/functions.php on line 168

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get_the_terms() is probably returning false.

Do a print_r($event_type_term) to see what you have in it.

From: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

> Array of term objects on success. False if no terms are found in the
>   given taxonomy and a wp_error object if an invalid taxonomy is
>   entered.

Comment: Ok, the thing is this only happens when adding a NEW custom-post. So for posts that do already have terms associated with it this doesn't happen. The problem is solved by adding this `if ( !empty( $event_type_term ) )`