# Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Tags: php, functions, warnings

Getting the following php error when trying to add a new post:

> Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php
>   on line 675

Here is the function:

```
function glossary_term_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if (false !== strpos($post_link, '%recipe_cat%')) {
        $glossary_letter = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'recipe_cat');
        $post_link = str_replace('%recipe_cat%', array_pop($glossary_letter)->slug, $post_link);
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Any idea what the issue is and how to resolve?

Comment: Check out [`get_the_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)

Comment: Similar question here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60570/array-pop-expects-array-boolean-given-for-event-type-term-slug

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_terms()` will return a `boolean` `false` under some circumstances:

> A post with no terms assigned gives a false result, not an empty
>   array.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms#Returns

It sounds like that is what is happening. You need to check that `$post_link =` to ensure that it is the `type` you expect before trying to use it.

Comment: How do you check `$post_link =`?